# Why isn't my player/tile collision working?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a tile based game and the tiles are rectangles appended to the tile list like so:

```
cell_rects = []
for y, row in enumerate(level):
    for x, cell in enumerate(row):
        if cell == 1:
            screen.blit(grass, (x * 50, y * 50))
        elif cell == 2:
            screen.blit(dirt, (x * 50, y * 50))
        else:
            screen.blit(air, (x * 50, y * 50))
        if cell != 0:
            cell_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x * 50, y * 50, 50, 50))
```

My player character is also a rectangle:

```
player = pygame.Rect([playerx,playery,50,100])
```

Here is the code I tried to make the collision work:

```
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    playery += -10
elif player != pygame.Rect.collidelistall(cell_rects):
    playery += 10
```

However, the terminal outputs:

```
  File "main.py", line 85, in <module>
    elif player != pygame.Rect.collidelist(cell_rects):
TypeError: descriptor 'collidelist' for 'pygame.Rect' objects doesn't apply to a 'list' object
```

How do I fix it so that the player and the tiles collide?

Edit: Here's the full program in case I missed anything.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800,450])
name = pygame.display.set_caption('Placeholder title')
gametimer = 0
walktimer = 0
walkframe = 1
playerx = 0
playery = 0
xvelocity = 0
running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    logo = pygame.image.load('assets/sprites/logo.png')

    #player
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    stand = pygame.image.load('assets/sprites/player/stand.png')
    walk1 = pygame.image.load('assets/sprites/player/walk1.png')
    walk2 = pygame.image.load('assets/sprites/player/walk2.png')
    walkcycle = [walk1, stand, walk2, stand]
    jump = pygame.image.load('assets/sprites/player/jump.png')
    player = pygame.Rect([playerx,playery,50,100])

    #tiles
    air = pygame.image.load('assets/sprites/tiles/air.png')
    grass = pygame.image.load('assets/sprites/tiles/grass.png')
    dirt = pygame.image.load('assets/sprites/tiles/dirt.png')

    if gametimer > 60:
        screen.fill((142,230,255))
        #level_tiling
        exec(open('assets/levels/level.py').read())
        cell_rects = []
        for y, row in enumerate(level):
            for x, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell == 1:
                    screen.blit(grass, (x * 50, y * 50))
                elif cell == 2:
                    screen.blit(dirt, (x * 50, y * 50))
                else:
                    screen.blit(air, (x * 50, y * 50))
                if cell != 0:
                    cell_rects.append(pygame.Rect(x * 50, y * 50, 50, 50))
        #player_sprites
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            screen.blit(jump, player)
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            if walktimer > 1:
                walkframe += 1
                walktimer = 0
            else:
                walktimer += 1
            if walkframe >= 4:
                walkframe = 1
            screen.blit(walkcycle[walkframe], player)
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            if walktimer > 1:
                walkframe += 1
                walktimer = 0
            else:
                walktimer += 1
            if walkframe >= 4:
                walkframe = 1
            screen.blit(walkcycle[walkframe], player)
        else:
            screen.blit(stand, player)
        #walking
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            if xvelocity < 10:
                 xvelocity += 1
            playerx += xvelocity
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            if xvelocity > -10:
                xvelocity -= 1
            playerx += xvelocity
        else:
            xvelocity = 0
        #jumping
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            playery += -10
        elif player != pygame.Rect.collidelist(cell_rects):
            playery += 10
    else:
        screen.blit(logo, (0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pygame.display.flip()
    gametimer += 1

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Typically when you move things until they hit something, you first check if the target spot is empty (by testing if `pygame.Rect([playerx, playery + 10, 50, 100])` hits anything). If you don't hit anything, you make the usual move. If you do hit something, you have two options: Option 1 is to check how close the object(s) you hit are, calculate your final position, and move there. Option 2 is to repeatedly check if a move-by-1 would hit. If it would not hit, move by 1. If it would hit, end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at usages, `collidelist` and `collidelistall` seem to take two parameters: a `Rect` and a list. `collidelist` returns the first index in the list which the `Rect` collides with, or `-1` if there are no collisions. `collidelistall` returns a list of all the `Rect`s which collided. So the line

```py
elif player != pygame.Rect.collidelistall(cell_rects):
```

should instead be

```py
elif pygame.Rect.collidelist(player, cell_rects) == -1:
```

Comment: It might also be the case that they expect you to do something like `player.collidelist(cell_rects) == -1`, so you could try that too.

Answer (score -1):

You obviously have some problems in this part of the code:
`pygame.Rect.collidelist(cell_rects)`
But you didn't include that part of the code in the condition.